# Cómo hacer que una carpeta apunte a un repositorio GIT existente

Tags: git, gitlab

Buenas! tengo un problema con mi proyecto y los repositorios de GIT y no sé cómo solventarlo. Por mala práctica, no comencé como tenía que comenzar y creo que ahora arrastro problemas. Os cuento.

Tengo un proyecto subido en un hosting. Los archivos que hay en ese hosting no apuntan a ningún repositorio ni nada, allí lo subo mediante FTP y listos.

Por otro lado, tengo el proyecto en mi GIT, con diferentes ramas:

Master (aquí es donde hago el merge desde dev)
Dev (aquí es desde donde mi localhost subo los cambios)

El caso es que en el entorno de producción no trabajo con git pull, sino que subo los archivos directamente y punto.

Ahora he creado otro entorno más: preprod y he creado en mi proyecto git una nueva rama "preprod".

En la máquina donde tengo preprod mal de mi no he hecho un git clone, sino que he metido los archivos directamente por FTP.

¿Cómo podría ahora, en esa carpeta, iniciar un repositorio e indicarle que ese repositorio es la rama  de mi gitlab? Los archivos son exactamente iguales.

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Yo haría `git clone -b preprod https://...gitlab...` en este servidor. Hazlo en un directorio diferente y compara con `diff` por si hay cambios que han pasado inadvertidos. En definitiva, nunca es tarde para hacer un `git clone`.

Comment: el tema es que no tengo composer instalado en el servidor, y el tema de los vendors puede ser un problema.

Comment: Tienes acceso shell a la máquina? En caso afirmativo, por qué no simplemente instalas composer? En caso negativo ¿Cómo podrías ejecutar comandos de git?